# Proving the identity of a group and the identity of the subgroup are the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, normal-subgroups

My question is suppose A is a subgroup of the group G. If e_G is the identity element of G and e_A is the identity element of A, how can I prove that e_G=e_A.

I was thinking of doing this by contradiction, but I am not too sure if this is the best approach.

Would a better choice be to use the identity property of groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: See if you can prove that $e_Ge_A=e_Ae_A$.  How can you then conclude that $e_G=e_A$?

Comment: Then should I start assuming e_G=e_A? Would this then involve the inverse property of groups?

Comment: No, that's what you want to prove, so you can't assume it.  Instead you'll just have to use the definition of $e_G$ being the identity of $G$ and $e_A$ being the identity of $A$.  You will need to use inverses for the second step (getting from $e_Ge_A=e_Ae_A$ to $e_G=e_A$).

Comment: okay, so I should pick some element in G say b so I can say b*e_G=b=e_G*b

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand somewhat. Well I would then use the inverse and rearranging the elements around.

Comment: Can you prove that a group has one and only one element satisfying the equation $x^2=x?$

Comment: @bof I am not sure I know how too...I just started learning about groups. I would think for example that only 1 works here

Comment: @EricWofsey Can I start with something like  since e_A is an identity on A and it is in A then e_A * e_A = e_A?

Comment: Yep, that's a good start!